# PHP Function wont print

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have built a php function to print the name of a person entered into my array, but it is not printing the names, it is only print the word .
Please let me know if you can assist me with this.

```
<?php

$names = array(0 => array(name =>"Becky", email => "@hotmail.com"),
            1 => array(name =>"Tom", email => "@yahoo.com"),
            2 => array(name => "Milduew", email => "@google.com")
);

function printInfo() {
echo "<table>";
foreach((array) $names as $name){
   echo "<tr><td>" . $name[0]. "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $name[1]. "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $name[2]. "</td></tr>";
   echo"</table>";
}

 }


 printInfo();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two main problems:

1. [Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). `$names` is undefined in the scope of `printInfo()`.

   You can alter your function to [take the array as an argument](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).

   ```
   function printInfo($names) { ...
   ```

   and then call it with `printInfo($names);`
2. The inner arrays in your `$names` array have string keys, but you are referring to numeric keys.

   You need to refer to `$name['name']` and `$name['email']` rather than `$name[0]` and `$name[1]`. (Incidentally, your input array only has two columns, so `$name[2]` would be undefined regardless.)

Also, there's no need to cast `$names` to an array (with `(array) $names` in your foreach loop), and doing so may actually cause problems. If you need to ensure that the input is an array, you can declare the type in the function definition.

```
function printInfo(array $names) { ...
```

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Oh, one more thing I just noticed. Your closing table tag is inside your foreach loop.

Answer (score -1):

Need to use following:

```
$name['name'] instead of name[0]
```